# Is there a common notation for "the rank of $x_i$"?

Tags: terminology, ranks

Such as $x^{\text{r}}_{i}$, or $\text{rank}(x_{i})$, or something like that?

(I just pulled those out of my bum, probably haven't seen them before.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, Wilxcon's 1945 paper introducing the rank sum test and signed rank test did not include any such notation for the rank of $x_i$ as I ask about, and only described ranking in the text. Mann and Whitney (1947) similarly do not give a notation for the rank of $x_i$, but only use $T$ as "the sum of the ranks of the $y$'s in the ordered sequence of $x$'s and $y$'s."

Some observations from notable literature on rank-based tests:

- In their 1952 paper motivating the Kruskal-Wallis test, Kruskal & Wallis used $R_i$ and $\overline{R}_i$ to represent the sum of ranks and the mean rank in the $i^{\text{th}}$ group respectively, but use no notation for the rank of the $i^{\text{th}}$ observation of $x$.
- Dunn's (1964) pairwise test *post hoc* to rejecting the Kruskal-Wallis null hypothesis, used $T_i$ to indicate the rank of $x_i$.
- Conover and Iman, in their (1979) presentation of a more powerful alternative than Dunn's test used $R_i$ for the rank of $x_i$ (with a different index to indicate the rank of a different variable, e.g., $R_j$ for the rank of $y_j$).
- Kornbrot uses $r(i)$ for the rank of the order statistic $x(i)$, and $t_a(i,j)$ as the rank of the differences $r(i) - r(j)$ in paired data (so $i=1$ corresponds to $j=1$).
- Conover's *Practical Nonparametric Statistics* uses the notation $R(X_i)$ for the rank of $X_i$ (e.g., in the rank sum test), and $R(X_{ij})$ for the rank of $X_i$ in group $j$ (i.e. in the Kruskal-Wallis test). Similarly, Gibbons and Chakraborti's *Nonparametric Statistical Inference* uses $r(X_i)$, but a different index for ranks in different groups (e.g., $r(X_i)$ vs $r(X_j)$).

**Conclusion:** It appears that "the rank of $x_i$" does not have a common and widely used notation in the originating texts of several of the most common rank-based tests, and in two popular textbooks on nonparametric statistics and inference. Explicitly used notations include $R_i$, $T_i$, $R(X_i)$, and $r(X_i)$.

**References**

Conover, W. J., & Iman, R. L. (1979). [On multiple-comparisons procedures](http://library.lanl.gov/cgi-bin/getfile?00209046.pdf) (Technical Report LA-7677-MS). Los Alamos Scientific Laboratory.

Conover, W. J. (1999). *Practical Nonparametric Statistics* (3rd ed.). Wiley.

Dunn, O. J. (1964). [Multiple Comparisons Using Rank Sums](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00401706.1964.10490181). *Technometrics*, 6(3), 241–252.

Kornbrot, D. E. (1990). [The rank difference test: A new and meaningful alternative to the Wilcoxon signed ranks test for ordinal data](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Diana-Kornbrot/publication/230264296_The_rank_difference_test_A_new_and_meaningful_alternative_to_the_Wilcoxon_signed_ranks_test_for_ordinal_data/links/5e7dda9ca6fdcc139c0902bf/The-rank-difference-test-A-new-and-meaningful-alternative-to-the-Wilcoxon-signed-ranks-test-for-ordinal-data.pdf). *British Journal of Mathematical and Statistical Psychology*, 43(2), 241–264.

Kruskal, W. H., & Wallis, A. (1952). [Use of ranks in one-criterion variance analysis](https://people.ucalgary.ca/%7Ejefox/Kruskal%20and%20Wallis%201952.pdf). *Journal of the American Statistical Association*, 47(260), 583–621.

Mann, H. B., & Whitney, D. R. (1947). [On A Test Of Whether One Of Two Random Variables Is Stochastically Larger Than The Other](http://webspace.ship.edu/pgmarr/Geo441/Readings/Mann%20and%20Whitney%201947%20-%20On%20a%20Test%20of%20Whether%20one%20of%20Two%20Random%20Variables%20is%20Stochastically%20Larger%20than%20the%20Other.pdf). *Annals of Mathematical Statistics*, 18, 50–60.

Wilcoxon, F. (1945). Individual comparisons by ranking methods. *Biometrics Bulletin*, 1(6), 80–83.

Comment: Suggestions to help me improve this answer welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is often the case that the rank of $X_i$ within the whole sample $X$ is denoted as $R_i$, i.e. (my notation),

$$R_i=\operatorname{rank}_{X_i \in X}(X_i|X).$$

This often appears in the derivation of the Wilcoxon signed-rank and rank-sum tests, so those might be a good source for alternative notation as well.